# Android - App crashes if I try to use its methods after binding

Tags: android, crash, android-service, android-service-binding

I have met a problem while trying to make an Android app. I have created a Service to be used by my main Activity. Following the guides I found on the internet, I do the binding on the `onStart` function.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
    textView.setText("Bound??????");
    if (mBound == false) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.mycompany.Messenger.LocalService.class);
        mBound = bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        //mBound = bindService(intent, mConnection, 0);
        //startService(intent);
        if (mBound == true)
        {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
            textView.setText("Bound");
        }
        if (mBound == false)
        {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
            textView.setText("UnBound");
        }
        boolean connected = mService.CreateConnectionNetwork();


   }
}
```

After the point at which I commend the binding, still inside `onStart` function, I try to call a method of the bind Service, which chekcs if there is a connection to the Internet. However, at that point the app crashes. As you note I have added a checking of whether the binding was successful or not, which comes out successful, making the matter even more confusing.

I have given the app the correct permissions, and the service's methods actually work if I initiate them through an event, e.g. button pressing. However, there are tasks that I want to be done automatically, when the app starts, and not after user interaction. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: I just formed my searching into a question, that if I had seen I would immediately understand why my app crashed -  it took me hours to find a comment implying the answer in some random stackoverflow question. I just could not understand why the service's functions would not work after the binding - not even the simplest call without any value assignment in the Activity, and nobody spoke about the asynchronous behaviour of service binding.

Comment: If you think the question is bad it's ok, but if the past me stepped upon this QA while searching, it would have saved me time. I am an Android beginner, and this QA is for other beginners too, that might face the same problem.

Comment: "it took me hours to find a comment implying the answer in some random stackoverflow question. " -- then upvote the question and comment, and propose edits to make it easier to find. If you had read the documentation for service, you wouldn't have attempted the code above.

Comment: Will try to find it then.

Answer (score -1):

The problem occurs due to the misunderstanding of the way services work. When you make the binding inside the `onStart` function, you just send the "Intent" (like a signal) to the system to perform the service binding. However, in theory you do not have any guarantee of when the binding will be complete. And in practice, you can be sure that the binding will only be complete after the `onStart` functions completes its work, hence the reason the service can be used via a button, for example.

If it's the first time the service is bound and you wish to perform some actions automatically when you are sure the service is bound, the best place to do this is inside the `onServiceConnected` function. When the said function is called, you can be sure that the binding is initiated, so after the chunk of code where the binding is complete (after the `mService = binder.getService();` in the code below) , you can add the code you want to be executed.

```
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName mConnection, IBinder service) {

        LocalService.LocalBinder binder = (LocalService.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mService.CreateConnectionNetwork();
        textView.setText("I just used the service and it did not crashhh!!!");

    }
```

Comment: The real problem there is that you were actually trying to update the UI from the `Service`. The service would notify the UI (`Activity`) of any changes it needs to make, i.e. through a Broadcast or LocalBroadcast.

Comment: You mean that merely calling the function would cause the UI to update? Without assigning any value.